# Xamarin.iOS app crashes on startup on iOS13

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

Few weeks ago I started to receive feedback from users that my app crashes on startup after they updated to iOS 13 beta. There has not been any similar issues with the older iOS versions. Previous version was built with the latest SDK available in April 2019. Now I upgraded to VS for Mac 8.2.6 (build 73), Xcode 11 previews channel, Xcode 11 GM 2 and rebuilt my app. App works fine in all iOS 13 simulators I have tested (also release build), but TestFlight users still say the app crashes on startup. I cannot test this with my own iPhone device since updating it to iOS 13 beta failed. I have investigated the crash log I received from one user but I couldn't find the reason for the crash. Any ideas what is the problem?

Crash log:

```
Incident Identifier: CA5B33CE-4FF3-xxx
Beta Identifier:     F9BF7B45-1AEA-xxx
Hardware Model:      iPhone9,3
Process:             MyCompanyMyAppiOS [1098]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/xxxxxx/MyCompanyMyAppiOS.app/MyCompanyMyAppiOS
Identifier:          com.mycompany.myapp
Version:             1.0.99 (1.0.99)
AppStoreTools:       11A1002b
Beta:                YES
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           com.mycompany.myapp [669]


Date/Time:           2019-09-17 21:22:13.1386 +0300
Launch Time:         2019-09-17 21:22:10.9000 +0300
OS Version:          iPhone OS 13.0 (17A5547d)
Release Type:        Beta
Baseband Version:    3.52.00
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGABRT)
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000018
VM Region Info: 0x18 is not in any region.  Bytes before following region: 4339662824
      REGION TYPE                      START - END             [ VSIZE] PRT/MAX SHRMOD  REGION DETAIL
      UNUSED SPACE AT START
--->  
      __TEXT                 0000000102aa0000-0000000102aa4000 [   16K] r-x/r-x SM=COW  ...ompanyMyAppiOS

Triggered by Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019ffc7ecc __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019fee3714 pthread_kill$VARIANT$mp + 324 (pthread.c:1445)
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x000000019fe388c0 __abort + 112 (abort.c:136)
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x000000019fe38850 abort + 112 (abort.c:107)
4   MyCompanyMyAppiOS               0x0000000104ccf10c xamarin_initialize.cold.1 + 0
5   MyCompanyMyAppiOS               0x0000000104cc5c2c xamarin_printf + 35806252 (runtime.m:2541)
6   MyCompanyMyAppiOS               0x0000000104ba5a70 mono_invoke_unhandled_exception_hook + 34626160 (exception.c:1287)
7   MyCompanyMyAppiOS               0x0000000104b3c40c mono_handle_exception_internal + 34194444 (mini-exceptions.c:2704)
8   MyCompanyMyAppiOS               0x0000000104b3aef0 mono_handle_exception + 34189040 (mini-exceptions.c:3028)
9   MyCompanyMyAppiOS               0x0000000104b3082c mono_arm_throw_exception + 34146348 (exceptions-arm64.c:390)
10  MyCompanyMyAppiOS               0x0000000103025c7c throw_exception + 172
11  MyCompanyMyAppiOS               0x0000000102db8844 System_Runtime_ExceptionServices_ExceptionDispatchInfo_Throw + 68
12  MyCompanyMyAppiOS               0x0000000102dbf4dc System_Runtime_CompilerServices_AsyncMethodBuilderCore__c__ThrowAsyncb__7_0_object + 108
13  MyCompanyMyAppiOS               0x00000001039a6404 Foundation_NSAsyncSynchronizationContextDispatcher_Apply + 15754244 (NSAction.cs:178)
14  MyCompanyMyAppiOS               0x0000000102fe2abc wrapper_runtime_invoke_object_runtime_invoke_dynamic_intptr_intptr_intptr_intptr + 284
15  MyCompanyMyAppiOS               0x0000000104b4e67c mono_jit_runtime_invoke + 34268796 (mini-runtime.c:3199)
16  MyCompanyMyAppiOS               0x0000000104c04ca4 mono_runtime_invoke_checked + 35015844 (object.c:3009)
17  MyCompanyMyAppiOS               0x0000000104c0867c mono_runtime_invoke + 35030652 (object.c:3064)
18  MyCompanyMyAppiOS               0x0000000102aab5e8 native_to_managed_trampoline_1(objc_object*, objc_selector*, _MonoMethod**, unsigned int) + 46568 (registrar.m:25)
19  MyCompanyMyAppiOS               0x0000000102abe020 -[__MonoMac_NSAsyncSynchronizationContextDispatcher xamarinApplySelector] + 122912 (registrar.m:16318)
20  Foundation                      0x00000001a05b5aa4 __NSThreadPerformPerform + 232 (NSThread.m:807)
21  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a014ccd8 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 24 (CFRunLoop.c:1922)
22  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a014cc30 __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 80 (CFRunLoop.c:1956)
23  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a014c3c8 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 180 (CFRunLoop.c:1992)
24  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a0147514 __CFRunLoopRun + 1080 (CFRunLoop.c:2882)
25  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a0146db4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 464 (CFRunLoop.c:3192)
26  GraphicsServices                0x00000001aa456328 GSEventRunModal + 104 (GSEvent.c:2246)
27  UIKitCore                       0x00000001a419de94 UIApplicationMain + 1936 (UIApplication.m:4687)
28  MyCompanyMyAppiOS               0x0000000103a14090 wrapper_managed_to_native_UIKit_UIApplication_UIApplicationMain_int_string___intptr_intptr + 400
29  MyCompanyMyAppiOS               0x0000000103954a44 UIKit_UIApplication_Main_string___intptr_intptr + 15419972 (UIApplication.cs:86)
30  MyCompanyMyAppiOS               0x000000010395499c UIKit_UIApplication_Main_string___string_string + 15419804 (UIApplication.cs:66)
31  MyCompanyMyAppiOS               0x0000000102b56f1c MyCompany_MyApp_iOS_Application_Main_string__ + 749340 (/<unknown>:1)
32  MyCompanyMyAppiOS               0x0000000102fe2abc wrapper_runtime_invoke_object_runtime_invoke_dynamic_intptr_intptr_intptr_intptr + 284
33  MyCompanyMyAppiOS               0x0000000104b4e67c mono_jit_runtime_invoke + 34268796 (mini-runtime.c:3199)
34  MyCompanyMyAppiOS               0x0000000104c04ca4 mono_runtime_invoke_checked + 35015844 (object.c:3009)
35  MyCompanyMyAppiOS               0x0000000104c0b04c mono_runtime_exec_main_checked + 35041356 (object.c:0)
36  MyCompanyMyAppiOS               0x0000000104b2c2e0 mono_jit_exec + 34128608 (driver.g.c:1321)
37  MyCompanyMyAppiOS               0x0000000104ccd23c xamarin_main + 35836476 (monotouch-main.m:0)
38  MyCompanyMyAppiOS               0x0000000102af14d4 main + 333012 (main.m:226)
39  libdyld.dylib                   0x000000019ffd2424 start + 4

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019feefadc start_wqthread + 0

.
.
.

Thread 11 name:
Thread 11:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019ffc7c9c __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019fee5168 _pthread_cond_wait$VARIANT$mp + 684 (pthread_cond.c:591)
2   MyCompanyMyAppiOS               0x0000000104caa3ec mono_os_cond_timedwait + 35693548 (mono-os-mutex.h:169)
3   MyCompanyMyAppiOS               0x0000000104c4e500 mono_w32handle_timedwait_signal_handle + 35316992 (w32handle.c:765)
4   MyCompanyMyAppiOS               0x0000000104c4e3d8 mono_w32handle_wait_one + 35316696 (w32handle.c:886)
5   MyCompanyMyAppiOS               0x0000000104c4e610 mono_w32handle_wait_multiple + 35317264 (w32handle.c:982)
6   MyCompanyMyAppiOS               0x0000000104c3daac ves_icall_System_Threading_WaitHandle_Wait_internal + 35248812 (threads.c:2167)
7   MyCompanyMyAppiOS               0x0000000104bcaf80 ves_icall_System_Threading_WaitHandle_Wait_internal_raw + 34779008 (icall-def.h:1143)
8   MyCompanyMyAppiOS               0x0000000102d45734 wrapper_managed_to_native_System_Threading_WaitHandle_Wait_internal_intptr__int_bool_int + 164
9   MyCompanyMyAppiOS               0x0000000102d451ac System_Threading_WaitHandle_WaitOneNative_System_Runtime_InteropServices_SafeHandle_uint_bool_bool + 284
10  MyCompanyMyAppiOS               0x0000000102d44c04 System_Threading_WaitHandle_InternalWaitOne_System_Runtime_InteropServices_SafeHandle_long_bool_bool + 84
11  MyCompanyMyAppiOS               0x0000000102d44b94 System_Threading_WaitHandle_WaitOne_long_bool + 84
12  MyCompanyMyAppiOS               0x0000000102d44a64 System_Threading_WaitHandle_WaitOne_int_bool + 84
13  MyCompanyMyAppiOS               0x0000000102d44b30 System_Threading_WaitHandle_WaitOne_int + 64
14  MyCompanyMyAppiOS               0x0000000102d4834c System_Threading_Timer_Scheduler_SchedulerThread + 284
15  MyCompanyMyAppiOS               0x0000000102d3e554 System_Threading_ThreadHelper_ThreadStart_Context_object + 212
16  MyCompanyMyAppiOS               0x0000000102d3bf58 System_Threading_ExecutionContext_RunInternal_System_Threading_ExecutionContext_System_Threading_ContextCallback_object_bool + 440
17  MyCompanyMyAppiOS               0x0000000102d3bd44 System_Threading_ExecutionContext_Run_System_Threading_ExecutionContext_System_Threading_ContextCallback_object_bool + 68
18  MyCompanyMyAppiOS               0x0000000102d3bcb8 System_Threading_ExecutionContext_Run_System_Threading_ExecutionContext_System_Threading_ContextCallback_object + 104
19  MyCompanyMyAppiOS               0x0000000102d3e6fc System_Threading_ThreadHelper_ThreadStart + 76
20  MyCompanyMyAppiOS               0x0000000102fe2abc wrapper_runtime_invoke_object_runtime_invoke_dynamic_intptr_intptr_intptr_intptr + 284
21  MyCompanyMyAppiOS               0x0000000104b4e67c mono_jit_runtime_invoke + 34268796 (mini-runtime.c:3199)
22  MyCompanyMyAppiOS               0x0000000104c04ca4 mono_runtime_invoke_checked + 35015844 (object.c:3009)
23  MyCompanyMyAppiOS               0x0000000104c0a728 mono_runtime_delegate_try_invoke + 35039016 (object.c:4342)
24  MyCompanyMyAppiOS               0x0000000104c433a8 start_wrapper_internal + 35271592 (threads.c:1188)
25  MyCompanyMyAppiOS               0x0000000104c4316c start_wrapper + 35271020 (threads.c:1240)
26  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019feec1f0 _pthread_start + 124 (pthread.c:895)
27  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019feefaf0 thread_start + 8

Thread 12 name:
Thread 12:
0   MyCompanyMyAppiOS               0x0000000104bea944 mono_mempool_contains_addr + 34908484 (mempool.c:356)
1   MyCompanyMyAppiOS               0x0000000104b51a84 mono_vcall_trampoline + 34282116 (mini-trampolines.c:826)
2   MyCompanyMyAppiOS               0x000000010302596c generic_trampoline_vcall + 252
3   MyCompanyMyAppiOS               0x0000000102eab92c System_Collections_Generic_ObjectEqualityComparer_1_T_REF_IndexOf_T_REF___T_REF_int_int + 300
4   MyCompanyMyAppiOS               0x0000000102cec738 System_Array_IndexOfImpl_T_REF_T_REF___T_REF_int_int + 184
5   MyCompanyMyAppiOS               0x0000000102ce8e24 System_Array_IndexOf_T_REF_T_REF___T_REF_int_int + 148
6   MyCompanyMyAppiOS               0x0000000102ea0044 System_Collections_Generic_List_1_T_REF_IndexOf_T_REF + 100
7   MyCompanyMyAppiOS               0x0000000102e9f4c0 System_Collections_Generic_List_1_T_REF_Contains_T_REF + 64
8   MyCompanyMyAppiOS               0x00000001040dfb4c Microsoft_WindowsAzure_MobileServices_PartialEvaluator__c__DisplayClass2_0__EvaluateIndependentSubtreesb__0_System_Linq_Expressions_Expression_System_Func_2_System_Linq_Expressions_Expression_System_Linq_Expressions_Expression + 23329612 (/<unknown>:1)
9   MyCompanyMyAppiOS               0x00000001040dff74 Microsoft_WindowsAzure_MobileServices_VisitorHelper_Visit_System_Linq_Expressions_Expression + 23330676 (/<unknown>:1)
10  MyCompanyMyAppiOS               0x00000001040dfd08 Microsoft_WindowsAzure_MobileServices_VisitorHelper_VisitAll_System_Linq_Expressions_Expression_System_Func_3_System_Linq_Expressions_Expression_System_Func_2_System_Linq_Expressions_Expression_System_Linq_Expressions_Expression_System_Linq_Expressions_Expression + 23330056 (/<unknown>:1)
11  MyCompanyMyAppiOS               0x00000001040df834 Microsoft_WindowsAzure_MobileServices_PartialEvaluator_EvaluateIndependentSubtrees_System_Linq_Expressions_Expression_System_Collections_Generic_List_1_System_Linq_Expressions_Expression + 23328820 (/<unknown>:1)
12  MyCompanyMyAppiOS               0x00000001040df528 Microsoft_WindowsAzure_MobileServices_PartialEvaluator_PartiallyEvaluate_System_Linq_Expressions_Expression + 23328040 (/<unknown>:1)
13  MyCompanyMyAppiOS               0x00000001040dd530 Microsoft_WindowsAzure_MobileServices_ExpressionUtility_PartiallyEvaluate_System_Linq_Expressions_Expression + 23319856 (/<unknown>:1)
14  MyCompanyMyAppiOS               0x000000010410fdd0 Microsoft_WindowsAzure_MobileServices_Query_MobileServiceTableQueryTranslator_1_T_REF_Translate + 23526864 (/<unknown>:1)
15  MyCompanyMyAppiOS               0x000000010410ea08 Microsoft_WindowsAzure_MobileServices_Query_MobileServiceTableQueryProvider_Compile_T_REF_Microsoft_WindowsAzure_MobileServices_IMobileServiceTableQuery_1_T_REF + 23521800 (/<unknown>:1)
16  MyCompanyMyAppiOS               0x000000010410ed10 Microsoft_WindowsAzure_MobileServices_Query_MobileServiceTableQueryProvider__Executed__7_1_T_REF_MoveNext + 23522576 (/<unknown>:1)
17  MyCompanyMyAppiOS               0x0000000102fe2abc wrapper_runtime_invoke_object_runtime_invoke_dynamic_intptr_intptr_intptr_intptr + 284
18  MyCompanyMyAppiOS               0x0000000104b4e67c mono_jit_runtime_invoke + 34268796 (mini-runtime.c:3199)
19  MyCompanyMyAppiOS               0x0000000104c04ca4 mono_runtime_invoke_checked + 35015844 (object.c:3009)
20  MyCompanyMyAppiOS               0x0000000104b32f58 mono_gsharedvt_constrained_call + 34156376 (jit-icalls.c:1466)
21  MyCompanyMyAppiOS               0x0000000102fe6b28 wrapper_managed_to_native_object___icall_wrapper_mono_gsharedvt_constrained_call_intptr_intptr_intptr_intptr_intptr + 152
22  MyCompanyMyAppiOS               0x0000000102f1af8c System_Runtime_CompilerServices_AsyncTaskMethodBuilder_1_TResult_GSHAREDVT_Start_TStateMachine_GSHAREDVT_TStateMachine_GSHAREDVT_ + 396
23  MyCompanyMyAppiOS               0x000000010410e6dc Microsoft_WindowsAzure_MobileServices_Query_MobileServiceTableQueryProvider_Execute_T_REF_Microsoft_WindowsAzure_MobileServices_IMobileServiceTableQuery_1_T_REF + 23520988 (/<unknown>:1)
24  MyCompanyMyAppiOS               0x000000010410e0ac Microsoft_WindowsAzure_MobileServices_Query_MobileServiceTableQuery_1__ToListAsyncd__33_T_REF_MoveNext + 23519404 (/<unknown>:1)
25  MyCompanyMyAppiOS               0x0000000102fe2abc wrapper_runtime_invoke_object_runtime_invoke_dynamic_intptr_intptr_intptr_intptr + 284
26  MyCompanyMyAppiOS               0x0000000104b4e67c mono_jit_runtime_invoke + 34268796 (mini-runtime.c:3199)
27  MyCompanyMyAppiOS               0x0000000104c04ca4 mono_runtime_invoke_checked + 35015844 (object.c:3009)
28  MyCompanyMyAppiOS               0x0000000104b32f58 mono_gsharedvt_constrained_call + 34156376 (jit-icalls.c:1466)
29  MyCompanyMyAppiOS               0x0000000102fe6b28 wrapper_managed_to_native_object___icall_wrapper_mono_gsharedvt_constrained_call_intptr_intptr_intptr_intptr_intptr + 152
30  MyCompanyMyAppiOS               0x0000000102f1af8c System_Runtime_CompilerServices_AsyncTaskMethodBuilder_1_TResult_GSHAREDVT_Start_TStateMachine_GSHAREDVT_TStateMachine_GSHAREDVT_ + 396
31  MyCompanyMyAppiOS               0x000000010410dfe8 Microsoft_WindowsAzure_MobileServices_Query_MobileServiceTableQuery_1_T_REF_ToListAsync + 23519208 (/<unknown>:1)
32  MyCompanyMyAppiOS               0x000000010429a72c MyCompany_MyApp_DataStore_Azure_ReminderStore__GetItemsForVehicleAsyncd__1_MoveNext + 25143084 (ReminderStore.cs:20)
33  MyCompanyMyAppiOS               0x000000010431ab04 System_Runtime_CompilerServices_AsyncTaskMethodBuilder_1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable_1_MyCompany_MyApp_DataObjects_Reminder_Start_MyCompany_MyApp_DataStore_Azure_ReminderStore__GetItemsForVehicleAsyncd__1_MyCompany_MyApp_DataStore_Azure_ReminderStore__GetItemsForVehicleAsyncd__1_ + 25668356 (AsyncMethodBuilder.cs:472)
34  MyCompanyMyAppiOS               0x0000000104299e8c MyCompany_MyApp_DataStore_Azure_ReminderStore_GetItemsForVehicleAsync_string + 444
35  MyCompanyMyAppiOS               0x0000000103f5ccc8 MyCompany_MyApp_Core_ViewModels_RemindersViewModel__LoadRemindersAsyncd__37_MoveNext + 21744840 (RemindersViewModel.cs:211)
36  MyCompanyMyAppiOS               0x00000001040516b8 System_Runtime_CompilerServices_AsyncTaskMethodBuilder_Start_MyCompany_MyApp_Core_ViewModels_RemindersViewModel__LoadRemindersAsyncd__37_MyCompany_MyApp_Core_ViewModels_RemindersViewModel__LoadRemindersAsyncd__37_ + 22746808 (AsyncMethodBuilder.cs:317)
37  MyCompanyMyAppiOS               0x0000000103f5aff0 MyCompany_MyApp_Core_ViewModels_RemindersViewModel_LoadRemindersAsync + 384
38  MyCompanyMyAppiOS               0x0000000103f5c99c MyCompany_MyApp_Core_ViewModels_RemindersViewModel__InitializeAsyncd__36_MoveNext + 21744028 (RemindersViewModel.cs:197)
39  MyCompanyMyAppiOS               0x00000001040515a8 System_Runtime_CompilerServices_AsyncTaskMethodBuilder_1_MyCompany_MyApp_Core_ViewModels_RemindersViewModel_Start_MyCompany_MyApp_Core_ViewModels_RemindersViewModel__InitializeAsyncd__36_MyCompany_MyApp_Core_ViewModels_RemindersViewModel__InitializeAsyncd__36_ + 22746536 (AsyncMethodBuilder.cs:472)
40  MyCompanyMyAppiOS               0x0000000103f5ae4c MyCompany_MyApp_Core_ViewModels_RemindersViewModel_InitializeAsync + 396
41  MyCompanyMyAppiOS               0x0000000103f5b660 MyCompany_MyApp_Core_ViewModels_RemindersViewModel__CreateAsyncd__8_MoveNext + 21739104 (RemindersViewModel.cs:79)
42  MyCompanyMyAppiOS               0x0000000104051020 System_Runtime_CompilerServices_AsyncTaskMethodBuilder_1_MyCompany_MyApp_Core_ViewModels_RemindersViewModel_Start_MyCompany_MyApp_Core_ViewModels_RemindersViewModel__CreateAsyncd__8_MyCompany_MyApp_Core_ViewModels_RemindersViewModel__CreateAsyncd__8_ + 22745120 (AsyncMethodBuilder.cs:472)
43  MyCompanyMyAppiOS               0x0000000103f59a40 MyCompany_MyApp_Core_ViewModels_RemindersViewModel_CreateAsync_MyCompany_MyApp_Core_ViewModels_VehicleViewModel + 400
44  MyCompanyMyAppiOS               0x0000000103fa033c MyCompany_MyApp_Core_ViewModels_VehicleViewModel__InitializeAsyncd__108_MoveNext + 22020924 (VehicleViewModel.cs:717)
45  MyCompanyMyAppiOS               0x000000010405c498 System_Runtime_CompilerServices_AsyncTaskMethodBuilder_1_MyCompany_MyApp_Core_ViewModels_VehicleViewModel_Start_MyCompany_MyApp_Core_ViewModels_VehicleViewModel__InitializeAsyncd__108_MyCompany_MyApp_Core_ViewModels_VehicleViewModel__InitializeAsyncd__108_ + 22791320 (AsyncMethodBuilder.cs:472)
46  MyCompanyMyAppiOS               0x0000000103f9c01c MyCompany_MyApp_Core_ViewModels_VehicleViewModel_InitializeAsync + 396
47  MyCompanyMyAppiOS               0x0000000103f9c268 MyCompany_MyApp_Core_ViewModels_VehicleViewModel__CreateAsyncd__100_MoveNext + 22004328 (VehicleViewModel.cs:470)
48  MyCompanyMyAppiOS               0x000000010405bc48 System_Runtime_CompilerServices_AsyncTaskMethodBuilder_1_MyCompany_MyApp_Core_ViewModels_VehicleViewModel_Start_MyCompany_MyApp_Core_ViewModels_VehicleViewModel__CreateAsyncd__100_MyCompany_MyApp_Core_ViewModels_VehicleViewModel__CreateAsyncd__100_ + 22789192 (AsyncMethodBuilder.cs:472)
49  MyCompanyMyAppiOS               0x0000000103f9b05c MyCompany_MyApp_Core_ViewModels_VehicleViewModel_CreateAsync_MyCompany_MyApp_DataObjects_Vehicle + 396
50  MyCompanyMyAppiOS               0x0000000103f966dc MyCompany_MyApp_Core_ViewModels_VehiclesViewModel__InitializeAsyncd__18_MoveNext + 21980892 (VehiclesViewModel.cs:198)
51  MyCompanyMyAppiOS               0x0000000102dbf1e4 System_Runtime_CompilerServices_AsyncMethodBuilderCore_MoveNextRunner_InvokeMoveNext_object + 180
52  MyCompanyMyAppiOS               0x0000000102d3bf58 System_Threading_ExecutionContext_RunInternal_System_Threading_ExecutionContext_System_Threading_ContextCallback_object_bool + 440
53  MyCompanyMyAppiOS               0x0000000102d3bd44 System_Threading_ExecutionContext_Run_System_Threading_ExecutionContext_System_Threading_ContextCallback_object_bool + 68
54  MyCompanyMyAppiOS               0x0000000102dbf074 System_Runtime_CompilerServices_AsyncMethodBuilderCore_MoveNextRunner_Run + 212
55  MyCompanyMyAppiOS               0x0000000102d5c5fc System_Threading_Tasks_AwaitTaskContinuation_RunOrScheduleAction_System_Action_bool_System_Threading_Tasks_Task_ + 124
56  MyCompanyMyAppiOS               0x0000000102d54708 System_Threading_Tasks_Task_FinishContinuations + 360
57  MyCompanyMyAppiOS               0x0000000102d529e8 System_Threading_Tasks_Task_FinishStageThree + 184
58  MyCompanyMyAppiOS               0x0000000102d4ce20 System_Threading_Tasks_Task_1_TResult_REF_TrySetResult_TResult_REF + 320
59  MyCompanyMyAppiOS               0x0000000102dbd878 System_Runtime_CompilerServices_AsyncTaskMethodBuilder_1_TResult_REF_SetResult_TResult_REF + 232
60  MyCompanyMyAppiOS               0x00000001042a742c MyCompany_MyApp_DataStore_Azure_VehicleStore__GetItemsAsyncd__4_MoveNext + 25195564 (VehicleStore.cs:40)
61  MyCompanyMyAppiOS               0x0000000102dbf1e4 System_Runtime_CompilerServices_AsyncMethodBuilderCore_MoveNextRunner_InvokeMoveNext_object + 180
62  MyCompanyMyAppiOS               0x0000000102d3bf58 System_Threading_ExecutionContext_RunInternal_System_Threading_ExecutionContext_System_Threading_ContextCallback_object_bool + 440
63  MyCompanyMyAppiOS               0x0000000102d3bd44 System_Threading_ExecutionContext_Run_System_Threading_ExecutionContext_System_Threading_ContextCallback_object_bool + 68
64  MyCompanyMyAppiOS               0x0000000102dbf074 System_Runtime_CompilerServices_AsyncMethodBuilderCore_MoveNextRunner_Run + 212
65  MyCompanyMyAppiOS               0x0000000102d5c5fc System_Threading_Tasks_AwaitTaskContinuation_RunOrScheduleAction_System_Action_bool_System_Threading_Tasks_Task_ + 124
66  MyCompanyMyAppiOS               0x0000000102d54708 System_Threading_Tasks_Task_FinishContinuations + 360
67  MyCompanyMyAppiOS               0x0000000102d529e8 System_Threading_Tasks_Task_FinishStageThree + 184
68  MyCompanyMyAppiOS               0x0000000102d4ce20 System_Threading_Tasks_Task_1_TResult_REF_TrySetResult_TResult_REF + 320
69  MyCompanyMyAppiOS               0x0000000102dbd878 System_Runtime_CompilerServices_AsyncTaskMethodBuilder_1_TResult_REF_SetResult_TResult_REF + 232
70  MyCompanyMyAppiOS               0x00000001042770f8 MyCompany_MyApp_DataStore_Azure_BaseStore_1__GetItemsAsyncd__11_T_REF_MoveNext + 24998136 (BaseStore.cs:54)
71  MyCompanyMyAppiOS               0x0000000102dbf1e4 System_Runtime_CompilerServices_AsyncMethodBuilderCore_MoveNextRunner_InvokeMoveNext_object + 180
72  MyCompanyMyAppiOS               0x0000000102d3bf58 System_Threading_ExecutionContext_RunInternal_System_Threading_ExecutionContext_System_Threading_ContextCallback_object_bool + 440
73  MyCompanyMyAppiOS               0x0000000102d3bd44 System_Threading_ExecutionContext_Run_System_Threading_ExecutionContext_System_Threading_ContextCallback_object_bool + 68
74  MyCompanyMyAppiOS               0x0000000102dbf074 System_Runtime_CompilerServices_AsyncMethodBuilderCore_MoveNextRunner_Run + 212
75  MyCompanyMyAppiOS               0x0000000102d5c5fc System_Threading_Tasks_AwaitTaskContinuation_RunOrScheduleAction_System_Action_bool_System_Threading_Tasks_Task_ + 124
76  MyCompanyMyAppiOS               0x0000000102d54708 System_Threading_Tasks_Task_FinishContinuations + 360
77  MyCompanyMyAppiOS               0x0000000102d529e8 System_Threading_Tasks_Task_FinishStageThree + 184
78  MyCompanyMyAppiOS               0x0000000102d4ce20 System_Threading_Tasks_Task_1_TResult_REF_TrySetResult_TResult_REF + 320
79  MyCompanyMyAppiOS               0x0000000102dbd878 System_Runtime_CompilerServices_AsyncTaskMethodBuilder_1_TResult_REF_SetResult_TResult_REF + 232
80  MyCompanyMyAppiOS               0x0000000104132b8c Microsoft_WindowsAzure_MobileServices_Sync_MobileServiceSyncTable_1__ToListAsyncd__24_T_REF_MoveNext + 23669644 (/<unknown>:1)
81  MyCompanyMyAppiOS               0x0000000102dbf1e4 System_Runtime_CompilerServices_AsyncMethodBuilderCore_MoveNextRunner_InvokeMoveNext_object + 180
82  MyCompanyMyAppiOS               0x0000000102d3bf58 System_Threading_ExecutionContext_RunInternal_System_Threading_ExecutionContext_System_Threading_ContextCallback_object_bool + 440
83  MyCompanyMyAppiOS               0x0000000102d3bd44 System_Threading_ExecutionContext_Run_System_Threading_ExecutionContext_System_Threading_ContextCallback_object_bool + 68
84  MyCompanyMyAppiOS               0x0000000102dbf074 System_Runtime_CompilerServices_AsyncMethodBuilderCore_MoveNextRunner_Run + 212
85  MyCompanyMyAppiOS               0x0000000102d5c5fc System_Threading_Tasks_AwaitTaskContinuation_RunOrScheduleAction_System_Action_bool_System_Threading_Tasks_Task_ + 124
86  MyCompanyMyAppiOS               0x0000000102d54708 System_Threading_Tasks_Task_FinishContinuations + 360
87  MyCompanyMyAppiOS               0x0000000102d529e8 System_Threading_Tasks_Task_FinishStageThree + 184
88  MyCompanyMyAppiOS               0x0000000102d4ce20 System_Threading_Tasks_Task_1_TResult_REF_TrySetResult_TResult_REF + 320
89  MyCompanyMyAppiOS               0x0000000102dbd878 System_Runtime_CompilerServices_AsyncTaskMethodBuilder_1_TResult_REF_SetResult_TResult_REF + 232
90  MyCompanyMyAppiOS               0x000000010410f190 Microsoft_WindowsAzure_MobileServices_Query_MobileServiceTableQueryProvider__Executed__7_1_T_REF_MoveNext + 23523728 (/<unknown>:1)
91  MyCompanyMyAppiOS               0x0000000102dbf1e4 System_Runtime_CompilerServices_AsyncMethodBuilderCore_MoveNextRunner_InvokeMoveNext_object + 180
92  MyCompanyMyAppiOS               0x0000000102d3bf58 System_Threading_ExecutionContext_RunInternal_System_Threading_ExecutionContext_System_Threading_ContextCallback_object_bool + 440
93  MyCompanyMyAppiOS               0x0000000102d3bd44 System_Threading_ExecutionContext_Run_System_Threading_ExecutionContext_System_Threading_ContextCallback_object_bool + 68
94  MyCompanyMyAppiOS               0x0000000102dbf074 System_Runtime_CompilerServices_AsyncMethodBuilderCore_MoveNextRunner_Run + 212
95  MyCompanyMyAppiOS               0x0000000102d5c208 System_Threading_Tasks_AwaitTaskContinuation_System_Threading_IThreadPoolWorkItem_ExecuteWorkItem + 72
96  MyCompanyMyAppiOS               0x0000000102d416c0 System_Threading_ThreadPoolWorkQueue_Dispatch + 608
97  MyCompanyMyAppiOS               0x000000010390e588 ObjCRuntime_Runtime_ThreadPoolDispatcher_System_Func_1_bool + 15132040 (Runtime.cs:288)
98  MyCompanyMyAppiOS               0x0000000102d43a30 System_Threading__ThreadPoolWaitCallback_PerformWaitCallback + 160
99  MyCompanyMyAppiOS               0x0000000102fe2abc wrapper_runtime_invoke_object_runtime_invoke_dynamic_intptr_intptr_intptr_intptr + 284
100 MyCompanyMyAppiOS               0x0000000104b4e67c mono_jit_runtime_invoke + 34268796 (mini-runtime.c:3199)
101 MyCompanyMyAppiOS               0x0000000104c066e8 mono_runtime_try_invoke + 35022568 (object.c:3009)
102 MyCompanyMyAppiOS               0x0000000104c3a0c4 worker_callback + 35233988 (threadpool.c:370)
103 MyCompanyMyAppiOS               0x0000000104c37e30 worker_thread + 35225136 (threadpool-worker-default.c:476)
104 MyCompanyMyAppiOS               0x0000000104c432e8 start_wrapper_internal + 35271400 (threads.c:1178)
105 MyCompanyMyAppiOS               0x0000000104c4316c start_wrapper + 35271020 (threads.c:1240)
106 libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019feec1f0 _pthread_start + 124 (pthread.c:895)
107 libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019feefaf0 thread_start + 8


Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000000000000   x1: 0x0000000000000000   x2: 0x0000000000000000   x3: 0x0000000000000001
    x4: 0x0000000000000000   x5: 0x0000000000989680   x6: 0x0000000000000039   x7: 0xffffffffffffffec
    x8: 0x0000000000000000   x9: 0x0000000000000801  x10: 0x00000000000003e8  x11: 0x0000000000bf3d01
   x12: 0x0000000144ba8000  x13: 0x0000000000004009  x14: 0x0000000144ba4000  x15: 0x0000000000003fff
   x16: 0x0000000000000148  x17: 0x00000001a00b8200  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000000000006
   x20: 0x0000000000000800  x21: 0x0000000000000407  x22: 0x00000001051b98e0  x23: 0x0000000143d01b50
   x24: 0x00000001446e41f8  x25: 0x0000000105384788  x26: 0x0000000144817800  x27: 0x000000016d35d250
   x28: 0x0000000102fe2abb   fp: 0x000000016d35c3c0   lr: 0x000000019fee3714
    sp: 0x000000016d35c3a0   pc: 0x000000019ffc7ecc cpsr: 0x00000000
   esr: 0x56000080  Address size fault
```

Currently known devices where the crash occurs: iPhone 7, iPhone X. Based on analytics data not all iOS 13 devices have this issue (exact device models are unknown).

Comment: The reason is quite simple actually your app is not built for iOS 13, the last time you released the application iOS 12 SDK was the highest that you had which means any iOS version above that will not be supported. To support iOS 13 you will have to download all the SDK's in your MAC then create a new API and release it...

Comment: @FreakyAli I mentioned in my question that I have rebuilt the latest version of my app using the latest SDKs and tools and it still crashes.

Comment: Umm, so you using XCode 11 and iOS 13 SDK's? Are you sure? I would suggest you check the XCode version once https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/ios-13-and-xcode-11/

Comment: Yes I am sure. Xcode 11 GM 2 (14936), Xamarin.iOS version 13.0.0.19, Apple SDK location set correctly.

Comment: Do you have XCode 11 compatible provisioning profiles? https://forum.unity.com/threads/new-provisioning-profiles-requires-xcode-11-so-where-is-the-support-for-that-unity.691150/

Comment: @kine `Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit)` do you know which device the customer use . And whether some Nugets or frameworks in project not suitable for IOS 13 .

Comment: How can I check the provisioning profiles compatibility? I have not updated them lately. Anyway, the latest version built with the iOS13 SDKs still works normally on iOS 12 devices.

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT The crash log is from iPhone 7

Comment: @kine Okey .if want to reproduce it , you can test it in a iPhone 7 to have a try .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Crash was caused by this code:

```
var allNotifications = UIApplication.SharedApplication.ScheduledLocalNotifications;
foreach (var notification in allNotifications)
{
...
}
```

In iOS 12 and earlier `UIApplication.SharedApplication.ScheduledLocalNotifications` returns empty array if there are not any scheduled local notifications. In iOS 13 it returns null. So adding a null check fixed the issue.

It may return null also because the API `UIApplication.SharedApplication.ScheduledLocalNotifications` has been deprecated since iOS 10. I upgraded now to the new API `UNUserNotificationCenter.GetPendingNotificationRequests` and noticed that the null check is needed also with the new API.

Comment: Good to know. Thanks

Answer (score 11):

Are you using Bluetooth? If so, have you added keys NSBluetoothPeripheralUsageDescription and NSBluetoothAlwaysUsageDescription to your Info.plist? My application crashed on start after updating to iOS 13 until I added them.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. This was not causing the crash in my case.

Comment: Adding both of these keys fixed our issue. The app was crashing on startup on iOS 13 until these keys were added. Thank you!

Comment: This did solve it for me -- I was having a similar crash while debugging.  I made this change and also DELETED THE APP from phone (not deleting it gave the same crash).

Comment: Solved it for us too! Thanks!

Comment: This solved my issue, I am using bluethoot in my app. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

To get console output for a crash like this on a release version on device:
connect your device to your Mac
open XCode
go to Window -> Devices and Simulators
click Open Console for your device
type your app name in the search window to filter the output

I found the exception that way. The crash log posted in the question didn't help, because it's just the apple main thread crashing.

For us the crash was caused by using a deprecated class, namely UISearchDisplayController, which should be replaced by UISearchController.
It continued to work in iOS12, but not in iOS13. It was deprecated in iOS8 though i think, so fair enough.

You may have to upload the app to App Store Connect and run it via TestFlight to see the logs, not sure.

Also, this is probably irrelevant, but go to your iPhone settings -> privacy -> Analytics -> Share with App Developers and Share iPhone Analytics

Comment: I'm not sure if this is my problem (yet), but I do have UISearchDisplayControllers... so I'm thinking this is it... I've spent HOURS googling and even if your response doesn't solve my issue, I really appreciate you posting. I'll write back when Apple finishes "processing" my updated build (WHY DOES THIS TAKE SO LONG BTW?). Thank you again for posting.

Comment: OK I finally figured it out... YOU SAVED ME. I never would have checked the damn UISearchDisplayController. So thank you! I'll post an image below as the answer, but YOU solved my issue. Thank you again.

Comment: i'm glad i could help :)
for others it may not be the UISearchDisplayControllers, but you should be able to find all sorts of errors in these console logs from XCode, especially when the main thread crashes.

Answer (score 0):

The image below shows 'Search Display Controller'. I wasn't even using this (as it was quite old) but somehow it caused an issue for iOS 13 (production build ONLY). I hope this helps others.

SIMPLY DELETE (or re-code) and production build now works.

All credit is given to @sschmidTU, thank you for your answer above.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I just had a situation where my app only failed to start on iOS physical device in release mode.  Finally tracked it down to a static class that was starting a timer with Device.StartTimer in the constructor.  It was being used slightly before global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(); was either called or at least completed.  I was getting no helpful logging information, but after remarking out most of my application and leaving just the splash screen, running debug on release version gave me a readable exception about not being able to use it prior to the Forms.Init.  I moved it from constructor to the initialization function for that class, and things are working.  The code had not previously caused issues, and ONLY caused the crash with the release version on a physical iOS device.  Nothing about it made it into the crash log in the analytics area.  Just another pattern to hunt for if you have one of these extremely frustrating no-start-no-info events.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was a double MtouchLink configuration in *iOS.csproj file :

```
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|iPhone' "> ... 
   <MtouchLink>SdkOnly</MtouchLink> 
   <MtouchLink>Full</MtouchLink>
```

VS was saving two linker behaviors configurations and the app was crashing after showing the LaunchScreen image (only in release mode).

To correct it just edit the *iOS.csproj file with a text editor and delete the one of the MtouchLink config :

```
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|iPhone' "> ... 
   <MtouchLink>SdkOnly</MtouchLink>
```