# Xamarin iOS Simulator Black Screen After Xcode 11 Update

Tags: xamarin.ios, visual-studio-2017, ios-simulator, xcode11

I am using windows PC and Xamarin.I have recently updated Xcode to 14 on Mac, I am able to use all SDKs up to 16.4 however I need 16.5. I am running VS 17.5.6 After the Xcode update, my Xamarin Forms app never loads. The iOS Simulator simply shows a black screen after the log in screen, so the log in screen displays fine. I have tried multiple other form factor simulators. All show the same symptoms.

Comment: Xamarin.ios version of the vs 2017 is not compatible with the Xcode 11.0.Update the Visual Studio to 2019(16.2.x) . It will support XCode 11.0 .

Comment: Does it work now?

Answer (score 3):

In my case, it goes black in iOS13 after launching.
After some googling, I found the solution for my problem which was unchecking/set to false "Supports multiple windows".
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You may be using a deprecated class like UISearchDisplayController that stopped working in iOS13. That caused the black screen for me.

See this answer on how to check your console output / crash logs:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/58217046/10295942

Answer (score 0):

In my case, simply switching from iPhone 11 to iPhone SE simulator did the trick.  I am assuming if this works, switching from the current selected device to a different device could be all you need.