# App crashes in iOS13+ while navigating from Tabbed Pages inside Master Details to Login Page

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am setting the Main Page as Login and then set the Home Page as Main Page, Home Page is Master Details page and in that Details page is the Home Tabbed Page which is the Tabbed page and whatever the navigation I am doing is on the tabbed page current page. In Logout I am trying to navigate to Login page.
I used -

```
Application.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new LoginPage());
```

Also tried -

```
Navigation.InsertPageBefore(new LoginPage(), this);
await Navigation.PopToRootPageAsync();
```

But it's getting crash only in iOS 13+ and working fine in below 13 iOS OS version.

Please help me....

Comment: what is the exception causing the crash?

Comment: @Jason It's not showing anything in the application output window there is some traces related to UIView I will share you right back.

Comment: then wrap the suspect code in a try/catch block so you can catch the exception

Comment: @Jason The same code is working fine in iOS version less than 13.

Comment: @Jason I already added the try catch block but it's not going even in catch, it's strange behaviour I am facing now with tabbed page, if I remove tabbed page and set the details page to any other page then it's working fine.

Comment: XCode may be able to output an error that helps. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58217046/8395242) for help.

Comment: @Andrew It's not crashing in startup or any other, it's only crashes if I tried to remove the tabbed page from stack.

Comment: I understand. I just thought maybe XCode could catch the message where VS wasn't.

Comment: Can you please share us a sample project which can reproduce this issue? Or some error logs, stacktrace.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you look at the **XCode Console** when your app crashes
After you connect your iPad to your Mac via dock cable, you can start XCode and go to Window -> Devices and Simulators.

The window that pops up allows you to open the device logs and start the Console application. The Console application will list debugging information that are being streamed from the device in real-time. This is very handy when you want to trigger some feature and observe a resulting error.